# sp_send_dbmail: FROM_ADDRESS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. When I execute `sp_send_dbmail` I can't change the `FROM_ADDRESS` from the default one that our DBA specified. Why is there this parameter if it doesn't work? **How do I specify a "custom" `FROM_ADDRESS`?**

Comment: What does "can't change" mean? Do you get an error message (and if so, what is it)? Or do you get the e-mail but your `@from_address` hasn't been changed?

Comment: SQL Server seems to send it using the "custom display name" of the default profile of SQL Server if you don't specify the "custom display name". It doesn't make sense - should just show e-mail address as "custom display name" is you are changing the "from address". I guess you have to be explicit and tell it what name to use - it is not smart enough to take the e-mail address and make that the "custom display name"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Did you try in this exact format:

```
@from_address = 'custom display name <custom_address@your_domain.com>'
```

? Also, [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx), you need to be sure that your SMTP server will accept an override - it may be getting rejected at the server and has nothing to do with your code.

Finally, it is possible that under 2005 compatibility mode, the `@profile_name` will not be visible. (I can't confirm this right now, but this was a new parameter added in SQL Server 2008.)

Comment: I guess if you don't specify the "custom display name" it takes that from some SQL Profile. I would have assumed that if you are setting a "from_address" then if you don't specify the "custom display name" it should put the "from_address" as the "custom display name". It doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

`@from_address = 'custom_address@your_domain.com'` should work.